# Load a trained Keras neural network model on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-2.7, neural-network, raspberry-pi, keras

I trained a neural network in Keras and saved it as an HDF5 file (*.h5). The aim is to classify data and distinguish between several classes directly on a Raspberry Pi Zero which is gaining data trough Grove sensors using the GrovePi shield.

I would like to perform the classification task on the Raspberry Pi in real-time using the trained Keras model. However, it is not possible to install Tensorflow on the Raspberry Pi Zero which is required to use the built-in Keras functions to load the model and classify incoming data. Is there another possibility to load a Keras model in Python and classify the data without using the Tensorflow or Keras packages?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't get why it is not possible to install TensorFlow in the RPI zero.

Comment: Well, according to https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/issues/43 it is not possible, but maybe it changed. When I tried, I had some issues as well, but my internet connection was very unstable. I will give it another try today.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following link to install Keras on Raspberry PI 3

[Install Keras on Raspberry PI 3](https://medium.com/@paroskwan/layman-installation-guide-for-keras-and-tensorflow-on-rpi-3-38b84f3e59dc)

I am copy pasting the commands from the above post. Please don't forget to upvote his post. We should give him due credit for this wonderful post on Medium.

```
wget https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/releases/download/v1.1.0/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_armv7l.whl
sudo pip3 install tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_armv7l.whl
sudo pip3 uninstall mock
sudo pip3 install mock
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev 
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install gfortran
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-h5py
sudo pip3 install keras 
sudo apt-get install python3-skimage
```

Comment: Thanks for your post but unfortunately I cannot install tensorflow following the instructions on https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi on my Raspberry Pi Zero. I think this version only works with Raspberry Pi 3 and maybe 2. Do you know how to export a Keras model without using Keras and/or Tensorflow?

Comment: According to a colleague at the university, it is not possible to install tensorflow on the Raspberry Pi Zero because there is no compiled version for for the chipset which is being used. Therefore, I have to get a Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install pre-built version.

It could be a limited ram issue. When you install tensorflow on any raspberry pi, it is suggested to add --no-cache option

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-h5py python-opencv
pip install numpy scipy h5py opencv enter code here
pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow
pip install keras==2.1.5 --no-cache-dir --no-deps
```

It is important to pay attention to which Python version you are installing to. In my above script, I installed to Python 2.7. According to tensorflow page:
[Installing Tensorflow on Raspbian](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_raspbian)

> This can take some time on certain platforms like the Pi Zero, where some Python packages like scipy that TensorFlow depends on need to be compiled before the installation can complete. **The Python 3 version will typically be faster to install because piwheels.org has pre-built versions of the dependencies available, so this is our recommended option.**

So based on the above quote, it might be better to install on python 3. But my personal experience told me that it was actually easier to install on python 2.7.

Check my blog for step-by-step instructions: [Deep Learning with Raspberry Pi](http://funofdiy.blogspot.com/2018/08/deep-learning-with-raspberry-pi.html). 
I did installed on RPI 3, however I don't see why it wounldn't work on Pi Zero

Comment: Do you think the OP means Pi or Pi Zero? Not clear to me (and hence whether your answer is a complete one).

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a late replay, but it may be usefull for others

this post [Installing Latest Tensorflow and keras on Raspberry pi](https://medium.com/@abhizcc/installing-latest-tensor-flow-and-keras-on-raspberry-pi-aac7dbf95f2), has .whl of tensorflow which can be installed on Raspberry pi 2/3 and Raspberry pi one/zero with openblas

hope it helps.